# Call to RestTemplate never returns

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-security

I'm using a Centos machine to run a java Program with this code:

```
log.debug("Making call using RestTemplate.");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
log.debug("Returning from call using RestTemplate.");
```

From the logs and step debugging in Eclipse I can verify that the call new RestTemplate() is never returning. This same code works on other Centos machines but for mine never returns. I have tried running as root user also but this does not solve the problem. Not sure if this is a Spring question, Linux question or both?

Comment: which server is app hosted on? Do you see any warnings / error in server logs ? if yes please share them. Also may sound trivial but are you able to hit the particular URL from your machine ?

Comment: It's running my local machine which is running Centos 6.6. No warning / error from the logs. Nothing from the logs to help point a possible error. Yes, I can hit the URL from my machine (but it never even gets to that point). Also, I have even disabled iptables to ensure that is not causing the problem.